# Options API - Validation Callback $input is NULL

Tags: plugin-development, options

Issue is that the validation callback function for my plugin has NULL as the $input value.

It's my understanding that the validation callback will use the $input parameter, which contains the POST fields. But when I test the validation callback, the $input parameter is NULL, even though settings are checked.

Note that the settings page has just checkboxes; no other input field types.

My register_settings is as follows; it is tied to the admin_init hook.

```
register_setting( 
   'pluginPage',    // option group name
    'Settings Name',    // option name (used to store into wp-options
    array('sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_callback' // sanitize the data function')
    );
```

And the sanitize_data callback:

```
 function sanitize_callback($input)
    { $new_input = array();
  // ... some checking here, setting $new_input array values if $input array value exists
  return $new_input;}
```

Because $input is NULL, which I have verified with a `print_r($input);exit;` at the beginning of the `sanitize_callback()` function, the options are not saved in wp-options.

The only way I can get options saved is to use $_POST variables in the sanitize_callback function. That will properly store the options.

So, why is the `sanitize_callback` function not receiving the $_POST variables when the form is submitted?

Note that I have followed the instructions in the Settings API; I have verified all code is correct according to those instructions. The form is displayed with this code, so the nonce is in the form.

```
<form action='options.php' method='post'>
        <?php
        settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );    // initializes all of the settings fields
        do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );   // does the settings section
        submit_button();    // creats the submit button
        ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in the meantime you figured in out already. Though I want to share my experience since I faced the same problem and it might be useful for others.

In my case I just got the reference to the options wrong when creating the HTML code for the input-elements.

So since Wordpress suggests to have one option saving an array of values that are the actual settings of your plugin/theme/whatever, you'll problaby have something like this somewhere:
(Note: I will use `plugin_config` where you you have `Settings Name`, Rick.)

```
add_option('plugin_config', array(
    'val1' => 1,
    'val2' => 2'
));
```

Then in addition to registering the settings somwhere you will have registered the corresponding fields to enter values for the section, like this:

```
add_settings_field('val1_field', 'Field Label:', 'creat_html_callback', 'settings_page_slug_name');
```

Now the intresting part; when defining the html code, you have to set the name of the field in a way that wordpress can associate the corresponding post value of the request to the correct array position of the option `plugin_config` (your `Settings Name`!). So here is the callback referenced in `add_settings_field` before

```
public function creat_html_callback() {
    $option = get_option('plugin_config');
    echo '<input type="text" id="val1Field" name="plugin_config[val1]" size="10" value="'.$option['val1'].'"/>';
}
```

The essentiell part for me was **`name="plugin_config[val1]"`**. The name of the html-input-element must be the same as the registered (`register_setting`!) option/setting or the name of the option together with the array index of the value corresponding to the input field.
Of course this seems clear and easy to see. Bit I think  whith all those slug-names and references you can get easily confused especially when following a tutorial like [this](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/).